# Entity Framework Code first (existing database) Multiple dbContext Foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship, dbcontext

I am currently in design phase of a large application. The database has various sachems and each schemas has various database objects such as tables/sp/views etc.

In EF code first (with database first - to existing database), I have dbcontexts objects per database schema. I believe to have multiple dbcontexts is a good idea in a large database where there are hundreds of tables.

My problem is that how to handle a foreign key in schema1.tableA with schema2.tableA i.e. cross dbcontext foreign keys?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean for example how to lazy load references that exists in another dbcontext?

Comment: Thats right. Doesnt matter if its lazy load or not. Just need to know how to have reference between datacontexts in terms of FKs